# Cant install ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: 18.04, server

We're trying to install ubuntu server 18.04 on sbb-b64dv4/en player, before installing server we had desktop version of ubuntu on it and it worked fin, now when we install server it boots one time and after reboot no sign of living, we're out of ideas, can someone help

Comment: Please give more details on your hardware.  Look very closely at your screen.  For some reason the screen may have dimmed and the login is there. You can type the useraname hit enter and then the password. See if it comes up.

Comment: CPUAMD Bald Eagle RX425BB (2.5GHz Quad)
N/BIntegrated.
S/BBolton-E4.
GPUAMD R6 Graphics.
FDM/HDD/SSDSSD 64GB.
Memory4GB (DDR3 SO-DIMM 2GB x 2)
EthernetGbE Ethernet (RJ-45)

no, it boots one time normally, and then loops on the boot menu, when you can choose which hard to use, or lan